# How to represent a general movie in a cover picture for illustration purpose?

Tags: website-design, interface-design, illustration, symbolism

I'm making a SaaS landing page, and in the upper section there's an interactive illustration of the product (a web interface) in a browser, showing what you can do with the product.

[image: Screenshot of the illustration]

This interface has a banner that the customers can change (black box in the screenshot) and **I want to show with an example that the product can be used in the movie industry**. But I'm struggling to create something that transmit this message without actually creating a banner about a real or fake movie.

For sports, I took a photo of supporters. For music, I took a photo of a musician.

But for movies ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A picture of a movie theater?

[image: http://www.traversecityfilmfest.org/statetheatre/historyphotos/interior.jpg]
[source](http://www.traversecityfilmfest.org/statetheatre/historyphotos/interior.jpg)

Maybe add some animation and on window load move the curtains from a left-right 200px in view to something like 100px. Giving it the feel like the movie is starting?

### OR

Another option is to have the user choose it's favorite movie from a predefined list when browsing the page and upon selection, fetch a sequence from that movie and add it in the banner.

### OR

You can create an image of a movie premiere and it should always chance upon refresh or as a slider with the title of the most popular IMDB movie titles from the current year.

Comment: Thanks, but the blurred background behind the illustration is already a movie theater. I'd like the banner to make the visitor feel like it can be *his* movie in the header.

Comment: @ryancey Well then, another option is to have the user choose it's favorite movie from a predefined list when browsing the page and upon selection, fetch a sequence from that movie and add it in the banner.

Comment: Or you can create an image of a movie premiere and it should always chance upon refresh or as a slider with the title of the most popular IMDB movie titles from the current year.

Comment: After consideration, I finally went for the movie theater. It's the most general way to transmit the idea. What was holding me back was that it doesn't transmit the idea *"Put your own movie cover picture here"* but more something like *"It also works for the movie industry"*, but eh, can't satisfy everybody... For the answers involving real movies, I didn't want to do it for legal reasons. Thanks to all of you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Just to dump some ideas... popcorn? Film strips? Clapboards? Red carpets? [Something being filmed](http://digitalbloggers.com/bradleytomkins/files/2014/12/VM_BeginnerVideo_00.jpg)? The last one can be pretty versatile too; if you ever want to change what is being filmed, you can probably photoshop the images in the camera and background to be different.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for something very recognisable, like a popular animation movie. (Finding Dory, Zootopia, or maybe just Big Buck Bunny?).

This way it won't easily be mistaken for a still picture.

Comment: I'd rather avoid references to real movies for legal reasons.

Comment: @ryancey this is why I mentioned Big Buck Bunny: https://peach.blender.org/about/

Comment: My bad, I thought it was another popular movie, didn't know it was CC.